# Migration for changing belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `categories` currently they belong to `product` but I'd like them to belong to `store` instead. I have several thousand of these so what I'd like to do is create a migration that adds a `store_id` to categories and then, gets the associated `product.store.id` from it's current association and adds that to the `store_id`. After that I'd like to remove the product association.

Does anybody know how to easily and safely achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Should you add the association in the wrong direction, you can use `change_table` to reverse the association:

```
class CreateFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :favorites do |t|
      t.belongs_to :article

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class RemoveArticleFromFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_table :favorites do |t|
      t.remove_references :article
    end
  end
end

class AddFavoriteToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_table :article do |t|
      t.belongs_to :favorite
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First rename column to store_id,

```
rename_column :categories, :product_id, :store_id
```

Then change the assosciation.

Now you can either write a rake task to transfer the data or you can manually do it via console.
It's better way to write a rake task.

According to your requirement your rake task can be, get the store from the product and assign to the category according to your requirement.

```
require 'rake'

    namespace :category do
        task :product_to_store => :environment do
            Category.all.each do |category|
                product = Product.find(category.store_id) //you will get product,as now it chnaged to store_id 
                if product.present?
                    category.store_id = product.try(:store).try(:id) //assign the product's store_id to the category, use try to reject errored records
                    category.save
                end    
            end
        end 
    end 

Now run, **`rake category:product_to_store`**, thats it, the data gets transfered.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add new migration that will create the new reference with categories as store.

```
class YourMigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_reference :categories, :store, index: true
    Category.all.each do |category|
      category.store_id = category.product_id
      category.save
    end
    remove_column :product_id
  end

  def down
    add_reference :categories, :product, index: true
    Category.all.each do |category|
      category.product_id = category.store_id
      category.save
    end
    remove_reference :categories, :store, index: true
  end
end
```

May be if you have added the product reference and index then write the same as the store so then it will delete the index as well.

Answer (score -1):

you have data in the column you don't want to lose, then use `rename_column`

Comment: but I still have to change the values.  As the product_id's obviously doesn't match store_id